# Update and sum query C# Access DB

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a simple query using query builder of VS2012 C# which updates the database in my winforms application. The database has 216 entries so far and it's taking a lifetime to update the database. How to reduce the time?
Should I make more queries for each column or is there something else?

```
UPDATE      StudentInfo
SET         PLO_1_Status = ?, PLO_2_Status = ?, PLO_3_Status=?,
            PLO_4_Status = ?, PLO_5_Status = ?, PLO_6_Status = ?, 
            PLO_7_Status = ?, PLO_8_Status = ?, PLO_9_Status = ?, 
            PLO_10_Status = ?, PLO_11_Status = ?, PLO_12_Status = ?
WHERE       (CMS_ID = ?)
```

And here is how I'm calling this query in C#. I am using QueryBuilder and DatasetDesigner and Access DB

```
for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
{
    this.studentInfoTableAdapter.UpdatePLO_Overall(
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO1[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO2[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO3[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO4[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO5[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO6[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO7[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO8[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO9[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO10[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO11[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO12[i]),
        CMS_ID_Var[i].ToString());
   this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
}
```

Code for calculating `PercentageFormula`:

```
while (courseCounter < CourseNames.Count)
           {
               courseCounter++;
               for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
               {

                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[0], PercentageFormula_PLO1, Student_PLO_1_Sum, PLO_Contributor[0 * courseCounter], PLO1_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[2], PercentageFormula_PLO2, Student_PLO_2_Sum, PLO_Contributor[1 * courseCounter], PLO2_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[4], PercentageFormula_PLO3, Student_PLO_3_Sum, PLO_Contributor[2 * courseCounter], PLO3_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[6], PercentageFormula_PLO4, Student_PLO_4_Sum, PLO_Contributor[3 * courseCounter], PLO4_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[8], PercentageFormula_PLO5, Student_PLO_5_Sum, PLO_Contributor[4 * courseCounter], PLO5_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[10], PercentageFormula_PLO6, Student_PLO_6_Sum, PLO_Contributor[5 * courseCounter], PLO6_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[12], PercentageFormula_PLO7, Student_PLO_7_Sum, PLO_Contributor[6 * courseCounter], PLO7_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[14], PercentageFormula_PLO8, Student_PLO_8_Sum, PLO_Contributor[7 * courseCounter], PLO8_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[16], PercentageFormula_PLO9, Student_PLO_9_Sum, PLO_Contributor[8 * courseCounter], PLO9_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[18], PercentageFormula_PLO10, Student_PLO_10_Sum, PLO_Contributor[9 * courseCounter], PLO10_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[20], PercentageFormula_PLO11, Student_PLO_11_Sum, PLO_Contributor[10 * courseCounter], PLO11_Status, PercentagePassing);
                   PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[22], PercentageFormula_PLO12, Student_PLO_12_Sum, PLO_Contributor[11 * courseCounter], PLO12_Status, PercentagePassing);

               }

           }
private void PLO_Overall(int i, double PLO_Percentage, List<double> PLO_Formula,List<double> PLO_Sum ,double PLO_Contributor,List<string> PLO_Status,double PercentagePassing)
    {

            if (PLO_Percentage != 0)
            {
                PLO_Formula.Add(Math.Round(PLO_Sum[i] / PLO_Percentage * PLO_Contributor));
                if (PLO_Formula[i] >= PercentagePassing)
                {
                    PLO_Status.Add("Pass");
                }
                else
                {
                    PLO_Status.Add("Fail");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                PLO_Formula.Add(0);
                PLO_Status.Add("Not Decided");
            }

    }
```

Comment: code is working fine but its working damn slow @RobertSynder.

Comment: And just at a quick glance I think this is the problem `this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);` move it outside of your for loop

Comment: i have tried this . its still slow. @robertSynder

Comment: i dont know why its slow. data is too small and time its taking is like 15 sec.

Comment: The next step to figuring out what is slow is to break apart method into testable bits of code that you can run without your Winforms GUI. I'm not sure if VS2012 has a timing ability in the debugger, but I know that VS2015 does. I can give an example as an answer if you'd like

Comment: Anytime Please .if that can reduce my time.

Comment: Can you do us all a favor and post more code? I would like to see this entire class, and any other classes that are needed to make this code compile. Thank you

Comment: before that, i am just calculating percentageFormula in a function. I have datatable with the id's of student. I am trying to alot percentage calculated to each student using their ID's.

Comment: Can you please post the full class, as well as the `StudentInfoTableAdapter` (I know it is autogenerated and if you can't figure it out that is ok). But the small snippets you have make it hard to figure out what the problem is, and I can't get the code to compile without more information

Comment: I am sorry, i can't figure it out how to put the code of studentInfoTableAdapter. Thanks for taking Pain :(

Comment: This question has entered the close queue for being incomplete/broken. Please [edit] the question to include sufficient context, e.g. a `for` or `while` loop outside a method scope makes the "big picture" quite hard to grasp - why not just paste the entire class(es) *as you have it (them) in your IDE*?

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be helping this is what I can figure is the class. I'll be editing again here shortly.

```
public class ProblemClass
{
    private StudentInfoTableAdapter studentInfoTableAdapter;
    private StudentInfoDataSet oBE_DB_1DataSet;
    private List<int> CMS_ID_Var;
    private double[] total_Percentage_PLO;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO1, Student_PLO_1_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO2, Student_PLO_2_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO3, Student_PLO_3_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO4, Student_PLO_4_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO5, Student_PLO_5_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO6, Student_PLO_6_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO7, Student_PLO_7_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO8, Student_PLO_8_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO9, Student_PLO_9_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO10, Student_PLO_10_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO11, Student_PLO_11_Sum;
    private List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO12, Student_PLO_12_Sum;
    private double[] PLO_Contributor;
    private int courseCounter;
    private List<string>  PLO1_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO2_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO3_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO4_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO5_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO6_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO7_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO8_Status;
    private List<string>  PLO9_Status;
    private List<string> PLO10_Status;
    private List<string> PLO11_Status;
    private List<string> PLO12_Status;
    private List<string> CourseNames;
    private double PercentagePassing;

    public void ProblemMethod()
    {
        while (courseCounter < CourseNames.Count)
        {
            courseCounter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
            {

                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[0], PercentageFormula_PLO1, Student_PLO_1_Sum, PLO_Contributor[0 * courseCounter], PLO1_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[2], PercentageFormula_PLO2, Student_PLO_2_Sum, PLO_Contributor[1 * courseCounter], PLO2_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[4], PercentageFormula_PLO3, Student_PLO_3_Sum, PLO_Contributor[2 * courseCounter], PLO3_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[6], PercentageFormula_PLO4, Student_PLO_4_Sum, PLO_Contributor[3 * courseCounter], PLO4_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[8], PercentageFormula_PLO5, Student_PLO_5_Sum, PLO_Contributor[4 * courseCounter], PLO5_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[10], PercentageFormula_PLO6, Student_PLO_6_Sum, PLO_Contributor[5 * courseCounter], PLO6_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[12], PercentageFormula_PLO7, Student_PLO_7_Sum, PLO_Contributor[6 * courseCounter], PLO7_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[14], PercentageFormula_PLO8, Student_PLO_8_Sum, PLO_Contributor[7 * courseCounter], PLO8_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[16], PercentageFormula_PLO9, Student_PLO_9_Sum, PLO_Contributor[8 * courseCounter], PLO9_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[18], PercentageFormula_PLO10, Student_PLO_10_Sum, PLO_Contributor[9 * courseCounter], PLO10_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[20], PercentageFormula_PLO11, Student_PLO_11_Sum, PLO_Contributor[10 * courseCounter], PLO11_Status, PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[22], PercentageFormula_PLO12, Student_PLO_12_Sum, PLO_Contributor[11 * courseCounter], PLO12_Status, PercentagePassing);

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
        {
            this.studentInfoTableAdapter.UpdatePLO_Overall(
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO1[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO2[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO3[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO4[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO5[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO6[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO7[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO8[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO9[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO10[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO11[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO12[i]),
                CMS_ID_Var[i].ToString());
            this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
        }
    }

    private void PLO_Overall(int i, double PLO_Percentage, List<double> PLO_Formula, List<double> PLO_Sum, double PLO_Contributor, List<string> PLO_Status, double PercentagePassing)
    {

        if (PLO_Percentage != 0)
        {
            PLO_Formula.Add(Math.Round(PLO_Sum[i] / PLO_Percentage * PLO_Contributor));
            if (PLO_Formula[i] >= PercentagePassing)
            {
                PLO_Status.Add("Pass");
            }
            else
            {
                PLO_Status.Add("Fail");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            PLO_Formula.Add(0);
            PLO_Status.Add("Not Decided");
        }

    }
}
internal class StudentInfoTableAdapter
{
    internal void UpdatePLO_Overall(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5, int v6, int v7, int v8, int v9, int v10, int v11, int v12, string v13)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void Fill(object studentInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
internal class StudentInfoDataSet : DataSet
{
    public object StudentInfo { get; internal set; }
}
```

Testing code like this is very difficult. It is hard to read, difficult to maintain and lastly is a HUGE pain to debug a small problem. First suggestion is to group things together into a class that need to go together. This is the first suggestion on finding out what is slow. So here is a much smaller version of the same code.

```
public class ProblemClass
{
    private StudentInfoTableAdapter studentInfoTableAdapter;
    private StudentInfoDataSet oBE_DB_1DataSet;
    private List<int> CMS_ID_Var;
    private double[] total_Percentage_PLO;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations1 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations2 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations3 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations4 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations5 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations6 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations7 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations8 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations9 ;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations10;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations11;
    private StudentCalculation StudentCalcuations12;
    private double[] PLO_Contributor;
    private int courseCounter;
    private List<string> CourseNames;
    private double PercentagePassing;

    public void ProblemMethod()
    {
        while (courseCounter < CourseNames.Count)
        {
            courseCounter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
            {

                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[0],  StudentCalcuations1 , PLO_Contributor[0 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[2],  StudentCalcuations2 , PLO_Contributor[1 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[4],  StudentCalcuations3 , PLO_Contributor[2 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[6],  StudentCalcuations4 , PLO_Contributor[3 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[8],  StudentCalcuations5 , PLO_Contributor[4 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[10], StudentCalcuations6 , PLO_Contributor[5 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[12], StudentCalcuations7 , PLO_Contributor[6 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[14], StudentCalcuations8 , PLO_Contributor[7 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[16], StudentCalcuations9 , PLO_Contributor[8 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[18], StudentCalcuations10, PLO_Contributor[9 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[20], StudentCalcuations11, PLO_Contributor[10 * courseCounter], PercentagePassing);
                PLO_Overall(i, total_Percentage_PLO[22], StudentCalcuations12, PLO_Contributor[11 * courseCounter], PercentagePassing);

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
        {
            this.studentInfoTableAdapter.UpdatePLO_Overall(
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations1.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations2.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations3.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations4.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations5.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations6.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations7.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations8.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations9.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations10.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations11.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                Convert.ToInt32(StudentCalcuations12.PercentageFormula_PLO[i]),
                CMS_ID_Var[i].ToString());
            this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
        }
    }

    private void PLO_Overall(int i, double PLO_Percentage, StudentCalculation PLO_StudentCalculation, double PLO_Contributor, double PercentagePassing)
    {

        if (PLO_Percentage != 0)
        {
            PLO_StudentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO.Add(Math.Round(PLO_StudentCalculation.Student_PLO_Sum[i] / PLO_Percentage * PLO_Contributor));
            if (PLO_StudentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO[i] >= PercentagePassing)
            {
                PLO_StudentCalculation.PLO_Status.Add("Pass");
            }
            else
            {
                PLO_StudentCalculation.PLO_Status.Add("Fail");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            PLO_StudentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO.Add(0);
            PLO_StudentCalculation.PLO_Status.Add("Not Decided");
        }

    }
}
public class StudentCalculation
{
    public List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO;
    public List<double> Student_PLO_Sum;
    public List<string> PLO_Status;
}
```

Since you showed us one method that is fairly easy to test and it appears to belong in the newly created `StudentCalculation` I moved it there and built a test specifically around it.

```
[TestFixture]
public class StudentCalculationTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var studentCalculation = new StudentCalculation();

        studentCalculation.UpdateOveral(0, 0, 0, 0);

        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO[0], Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status[0], Is.EqualTo("Not Decided"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var studentCalculation = new StudentCalculation();
        studentCalculation.Student_PLO_Sum.Add(1); //I guess this is 100% ????

        studentCalculation.UpdateOveral(0, 1, 1, 0.5); //not sure what any of these numbers mean

        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO[0], Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status[0], Is.EqualTo("Pass"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test3()
    {
        var studentCalculation = new StudentCalculation();
        studentCalculation.Student_PLO_Sum.Add(0.5); //I guess this is 50% ????

        studentCalculation.UpdateOveral(0, 1, 1, 0.6); //not sure what any of these numbers mean

        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PercentageFormula_PLO[0], Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(studentCalculation.PLO_Status[0], Is.EqualTo("Fail"));
    }
}
```

Quick note about what I did. I created a new project with the same name as the project I'm testing and added a `.Tests` to it. I then used NuGet to get NUnit. You don't have to follow those exact steps if you prefer a different test framework. If you've never heard of a test framework I highly suggest looking into it as it lets you test your code in isolation and (if done correctly) is fast. Those 3 tests take a grand total of 12 milliseconds to run. This tells us two things. One is that your method `PLO_Overall` (what does PLO stand for even???) which is the same as my `studentCalculation.UpdateOveral`. Is not the source of your slowness. Even if I were to go crazy with generating a bunch more test data for that to work with I really don't think the problem is there.And this is what the code looks like now.

```
public class StudentCalculation
{
    public readonly List<double> PercentageFormula_PLO = new List<double>();
    public readonly List<double> Student_PLO_Sum = new List<double>();
    public readonly List<string> PLO_Status = new List<string>();

    public void UpdateOveral(int i, double PLO_Percentage, double PLO_Contributor, double PercentagePassing)
    {

        if (PLO_Percentage != 0)
        {
            PercentageFormula_PLO.Add(Math.Round(Student_PLO_Sum[i] / PLO_Percentage * PLO_Contributor));
            if (PercentageFormula_PLO[i] >= PercentagePassing)
            {
                PLO_Status.Add("Pass");
            }
            else
            {
                PLO_Status.Add("Fail");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            PercentageFormula_PLO.Add(0);
            PLO_Status.Add("Not Decided");
        }

    }
}

public class ProblemClass
{
//...unchanged code omitted for brevity
    public void ProblemMethod()
    {
        while (courseCounter < CourseNames.Count)
        {
            courseCounter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
            {
                StudentCalcuations1.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[0],  PLO_Contributor[0 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations2.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[2],  PLO_Contributor[1 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations3.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[4],  PLO_Contributor[2 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations4.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[6],  PLO_Contributor[3 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations5.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[8],  PLO_Contributor[4 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations6.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[10], PLO_Contributor[5 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations7.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[12], PLO_Contributor[6 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations8.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[14], PLO_Contributor[7 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations9.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[16], PLO_Contributor[8 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations10.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[18], PLO_Contributor[9 * courseCounter],  PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations11.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[20], PLO_Contributor[10 * courseCounter], PercentagePassing);
                StudentCalcuations12.UpdateOveral(i, total_Percentage_PLO[22], PLO_Contributor[11 * courseCounter], PercentagePassing);
            }
        }
        //...unchanged code removed for brevity
}
```

So moving on. This would mean that I would have to test the StudentInfoTableAdapter and because I don't have any of that code, nor the Microsoft Access database you have I won't be able to test it. Hopefully with the hint that I gave you about trying out a testing framework will allow you to get the TableAdapter under test and then you can slowly start isolating all the methods and find out what is the slow one. Remember to do this is small progressive steps. Happy Coding.